# is there any python tip or trick for double loop to compre list?

Tags: python, list, loops, compare

I wanna make 'list' if pattern_list item in path_list.
but I can just think double for loop.. is there any python trick or tip for double loop?

```
pattern_list = ['vendor', 'device']
path_list = [
...,
'a/b/c/hardware/',
'a/b/c/device/',
'a/b/c/vendor/',
...,
]
```

Comment: Can you exaplin better what you want to do? It's very unclear

Comment: Doesn't really make much sense your question, surely you want to form a list of the paths that contain your pattern? and not a list of patterns that are in your path list?

Answer (score 2):

```
result = [x for x in pattern_list for y in path_list if x in y ]
```

Is this what you need to do?
These are called list comprehensions. You can put how many for's and if's inside. You can read more about them here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Please provide atleast some explanation along with your answer. The point is not to give an answer but also to explain what is going on. Thank you.

Comment: That's better, now the OP actually can understand what is going on.

Comment: sorry, it's first question, I didn't know that, thanks, later i'll do,

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) functions:

```
>>> filter(lambda path: any(p in path for p in pattern_list), path_list)
['a/b/c/device/', 'a/b/c/vendor/']
```